# Use multiple instructions in one RegExp(JS)

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var myText = <"input">
```

I want to cut the string down to only **input**. Is possible to define a regular expression, which does this? I know how to get rid of the **<"**

```
myText = myText.replace(/<"/,g,'')
```

But what about the end of the line? Of course I could just write another regular expression, like this:

```
myText = myText.replace(/<"/,g,'').replace(/">/,g,'')
```

But I´m sure there is an easier way, right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp that matches start or end of sequence

```
var myText = "<input>";
myText.replace(/^<"|">$/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use `.match()` method:

```js
var myText = "<input>";

console.log(myText.match(/[(a-z)]+/g)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [character class `[]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to specify any of the present characters:

```js
var myText = '<input>';
console.log(myText.replace(/[<>]/g, ''));
```

If you want to replace any non alphanumeric letters, you can do:

```js
var myText = '<input>';
console.log(myText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var myText = '<input>';
myText.replace(/<(.*)>/, '$1');
```

Or

```
myText.match(/<(.*)>/)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myText = "<input>";
console.log(myText.replace(/(^<)|(>$)/g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks. Let´s say I actually have an "/" which i want to remove, why does the following code don´t work?     var myText = "<input/>";
console.log(myText.replace(/(^<)|(/>$)/g, '');

Comment: /(^<)|(\/*>$)/g

Comment: Thanks! Copuld you explain, what the "\" does? @Choo Hwan

Comment: "\" Escapes special characters to ensure that the regular expression processor ignores the character after the backslash.